# Inspect HTTP requests made by Apache Wink client

Tags: apache-wink

I'm using Apache Wink to access a service, and trying to debug a problem where the server apparently does not recieve my request in the intended format (details below, but are probably immaterial). Is there a way I can make the Wink client to log the HTTP requests that it makes to the server, so that I can see what is being sent down the wire?

*Details: I'm using Eclipse Lyo to create a ChangeRequest in RTC (rational team concert) using their OSLC v2 REST APIs.(Eclipse Lyo internally uses Apache Wink). In doing so, even though I've set a "Filed Against" property in the ChangeRequest being submitted, RTC does not recognize it and complains that it is missing.*

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I think it's better to use a proxy to monitor the traffic. If your client runs on Windows, [Fiddler](http://fiddler2.com/) is a very nice tool.